# each time I run curl on php, the server will die. I have to restart the apache

Tags: php, apache, node.js, curl, notifications

Each time I run curl on php, the server will die. I have to restart the apache.

The code is the following: I am trying to connect to my notification server and push notifications.

I can, indeed, receive the notification, but the page with php-curl will never be open, and after that, my server will die(any pages can not be open, need to restart apache)

```
$url = 'http://myip:myport/send';
$fields = array(
    'channel'=>urlencode("mychannel"),
    'secretkey'=>urlencode("mypassword"),
    'property1'=>urlencode("from PHP"),
    'property2'=>urlencode("Hello jimmy!")
    );

$fields_string = "";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Supplement: It's a Amazon's EC2 server.
also, i found that if i run curl in terminal, it not returning anything but it works properly.

Comment: what does your apache error log state?

Comment: Why is it tagged with `node.js`?

Comment: Because im using node.js server to handle this curl.

Comment: also, i found that if i run curl in terminal, it not returning anything but it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a Windows machine. Are you using XAMPP or WAMP? 
Google "php cURL crashes with windows" or your specific package, try to update your cURL extension. The code have nothing to do with your server crashing!

Comment: It's most likely server config error, there's no reason for your script just to crash the server just like that with no error returned. Try to unload the cURL extension from your php.ini and then execute the same page. Then check the logs in your web server.

Comment: Looks like my node.js 's server.js is not returning anything . So the curl is keep running.